# how to reach the parent from vagrant/libvirt/qemu vm?

Tags: vagrant, qemu, libvirt

I'd like to use vagrant with libvirt and qemu/kvm on a Fedora 24 system but I can't figure out how to connect from the VM to MariaDB running on the host (parent).

In the past when I've used VirtualBox as a provider for Vagrant I could just connect to 10.0.2.2.  Is there an equivalent IP address for libvirt/qemu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using vagrant-libvirt then the IP would be 192.168.121.1 for the host os.

Refer to this section for more details https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/blob/master/README.md#management-network